# How to create a combined sequence of constant length but starting at different values in R?

Tags: r

If I have a vector:

```
c(17,18,19)
```

And I want to get

```
c(17:17+5, 18:18+5, 19:19+5)
```

Or in other words:

```
c(17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
```

How would I accomplish this in one line? Perhaps an essential R function I am missing? This can be done by sapply I am sure, but wondering if there was a non-iteration method.

Answer (score 3):

```
c(outer(0:5, x, `+`))
```

or

```
rep(x, each = 6) + rep(0:5, 3)
```

Comment: Okay is that the simplest way. I actually came up with that already by myself. Just wondering if there is a cool R function I get to learn today? :)

Comment: Wow the last one is really quite elegant. I like the ingenuity.

Comment: `outer` is definitely fastest.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a few easier ways, but here's an `mapply` method.

```
> x <- c(17,18,19)
> c(mapply(seq, from = x, to = x + 5))
# [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 18 19 20 21 22 23 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Or even quicker

```
> c(mapply(`:`, from = x, to = x + 5))
```

`mapply` is basically a *multi-apply*, for applying a function to multiple vector or list arguments.

The following actually proved slightly faster than `mapply`

```
> c(sapply(x, function(y) `:`(y, y+5)))
```

Comment: +1. Was just about to post `c(mapply(":", x, x+5))`.

Comment: @Robert Krzyzanowski Yep mapply is the cool function I would learn that I was talking about in the comments to your answer