# Creating a sequence in a specified order

Tags: r

I am looking forward to create a sequence using any of the methods in [How to create a combined sequence of constant length but starting at different values in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837589/how-to-create-a-combined-sequence-of-constant-length-but-starting-at-different-v)

Sequence I need is

```
1 3 5 2 5 8 3 7 11 4 9 14
```

Here, you can find a pattern.  First 3 numbers differ by 2,second set of 3 numbers differ by 3, third set differs by 4, fourth set 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n <- 1:4
diffs <- 2:5
times <- 3
out <- rep(n, each = 3) + c(outer(0:2, diffs, `*`))
# [1]  1  3  5  2  5  8  3  7 11  4  9 14
# or: out <- c(sapply(seq_along(n), function(i) seq(i, length.out = 3, by = diffs[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way:

```
as.vector(mapply(seq, 1:4, by=2:5, length.out=3))
# [1]  1  3  5  2  5  8  3  7 11  4  9 14
```